# external javascript file and function not working

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am new to javascript. I was trying to make a message box popup onload. As i am beginner i copied the code  from internet just to see how it works but for some reason the pop is not showing up. I know the code is not worng because it is wrking in the video.
the calling method is a bit different as i am using django.

**console error**

```
auto.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

**html code**

```
{% block content %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'auto.js' %}"></script>

<div class="popup">
    <div class="contentBox">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <h3 style="color: oldlace;">TESTING POPUP</h3>

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**javasript code**

```
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');

window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    popup.style.display = "block"

    // add some time delay o show

  }, 2000)
}
```

Comment: Load js after html is loaded.

Comment: The error means that `popup`  variable is null .You can always try portions of Javascript directly on the browser console , like `document.querySelector('.popup')`  . So maybe you need to include that declaration inside  setTimeout function .

Comment: @kamran890, the html is already loading, this is how actually a django template works other js file is working only not this

Comment: @jirarium, but why is it showing null when the code is absolutely working fine in the video from  whom i have learnt this

Answer (score 1):

You need to load js file after html:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="popup">
    <div class="contentBox">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <h3 style="color: oldlace;">TESTING POPUP</h3>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'auto.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thank you so much now it is working. thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

the syntax s document.querySelector(Selector)
I do not think .popup is a selector from your listing.

Comment: thank you so much, now it is working fine kamran's advice worked for me